# How to show dropdown-select list in jQuery popup and retrieve selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I would like to show a select-dropdown list in a jQuery Popup / Dialog. Could you please show me how to do this, and how to retrieve the selected value?

Example code below:

```
<div id='selectPopup'>
    <form name='test'>
        <select  id='inptPAN' name='inptPAN'>
            <option value='1'>item 1</option>
            <option value='2'>item 2</option>
            <option value='3'>item 3</option>
            <option value='4'>item 4</option>
            <option value='5'>item 5</option>
            <option value='6'>item 6</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doonot/pQJf8/9/) for some code

Comment: what popup or dialog do you use? Do you have some js code you tried so far so we could extend it?

Comment: $("#inptPAN").val() should do

Comment: btw, I don't know what is wrong with stackoverflow. I always get a virus warning when I refresh the page and I am not able to use the wysiwyg editor since today morning. Sorry for the wrong formatting.

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn I started on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doonot/pQJf8/9/), maybe you can work on that? I plan to use `jquery.ui.dialog`.

Comment: How to show dropdown-select list in jQuery popup and retrieve selected value on submit on controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="../../../Scripts/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // this function is triggered as soon as something changes in the form
            $("select[name='inptPAN']").change(function () {
                //console.log('found change');
              selectDialog('Pan','You had selected, Text: '+ $(':selected',this).text()+' And Value : '+$(this).val());
            });

            function selectDialog(title, text) {
                return $('<div></div>').append(text)
            .dialog({
                resizable: true,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='selectPopup'>
        <form name='test'>
        <select id='inptPAN' name='inptPAN'>
            <option value='1'>item 1</option>
            <option value='2'>item 2</option>
            <option value='3'>item 3</option>
            <option value='4'>item 4</option>
            <option value='5'>item 5</option>
            <option value='6'>item 6</option>
        </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/DmFXZ/)

Comment: I would like to use the standard jQuery UI script, not an altered one.

Comment: Please see my linked jsfiidle. I want to retrieve the value after the dropdown list changes, with jQuery of course. This function is already available in my jsfiddle.